# Checking for placeholder text using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a textbox that displays a placeholder text when the textbox is not in focus. When the focus is shifted to this textbox (by placing the cursor in the textbox), the placeholder text disappears and the cursor appears in the textbox. I am trying to automate a scenario which confirms this behavior. Has anybody ever tried to automate a similar scenario? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can get the placeholder text using the `getAttribute` method of webdriver.

The HTML:

```
<input id="<ur id>" class="<ur class name>" type="password" lang="en" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter Password" data-label="passwordPlaceholder" tabindex="5">
```

The Java code:

```
String password=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ur css path")).getAttribute("placeholder");
```

Answer (score 3):

I've done similar tests. For our fields with placeholder text, the text appears in a placeholder attribute on the element. In Ruby, we use code like this:

```
element = @driver.find_element(*<locator string>*)
expected_placeholder_text = element.attribute('placeholder')
```

That gives us a string that we compare just like any other string. You could also shorten the element.attribute call to be

```
element['placeholder']
```

as well, but we prefer the former (for non-relevant and completely arbitrary reasons).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to verify the actual behavior. You are just assuming that the HTML5 placeholder will make the browser behave properly.

Comment: And unless you're on the browser development team, why do you need to make sure that the browser is correctly doing what it says it will? What would you & your team do with a bug report for a browser not doing what it says it would?

From another viewpoint, if you've got an automated test that verifies the placeholder attribute is present and as expected in your app code, how long does it take to fire up a browser manually once per version & make sure the text appears? Could you build & maintain automation in less time?

Answer (score 0):

```java
String Hinttext=Name.getAttribute("placeholder");

if(Hinttext.equals("Enter Your Name"))
    System.out.println("Correct Hinttext is shown ......PASSED");
else
    System.out.println("Correct Hinttext NOT is shown ......PASSED");
```